# how Taylor series expansion is applied on the pixel array in python?

Tags: python, taylor-series

I wanted to compute Taylor series expansion of each pixel values from the pixel array. I am wondering how Taylor expansion is going to approximate each pixel values with certain approximation order. As far as I know, Taylor expansion works with fixed function, in my case, I am going to have feature transformation function which is going to make pixel vectors from image. I have following mathematical formulation and I am curious about what would be possible implementation in python:

[image]

where `alpha` is taylor expansion coefficient, `p` is taylor approximation order, `x` is pixel vector. I want to approximate each pixel values with taylor series expansion. How to make this happen? any idea?

**graphic intuition**

here is graphical demonstration of the idea that I am pursuing:

[image]

**my current attempt**

here is my current attempt and it is not working correctly.

```
   def taylor_func(x, approx_order=2):
        x_ = x[..., None] 
        x_ = tf.tile(x_, multiples=[1, 1, approx_order+ 1])  
        pows = tf.range(0, approx_order + 1, dtype=tf.float32) 
        x_p = tf.pow(x_, pows) 
        x_p_ = x_p[..., None]
        return x_p_

x = Input(shape=(4,4,3))
x_new = Lambda(lambda x: taylor_func(x, max_pow))(x)
```

I was expecting to approximate each pixel values with Taylor sires expansion, but above code is not giving correct taylor expansion output. any better idea?

**desired output**

here is the graphical illustration of my desired output:

[image]

in this graph, let's say we have 8 pixels which supposed to be approximated with taylor series, and would get 16 new pixels. I am wondering how to implement this more efficiently in python. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? any thought?